# I'm getting a error saying 'can't assign to literal'

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I'm trying to get this procedure to check whether the user lands on a treasure square and if they do they get gold. Also the treasure can only be landed on 3 times until it turns into a bandit, therefore after each time the player lands on it the tile's name changes, to `T2`, `T3`, `B`. Whenever I attempt to run my code an error appears saying `can't assign to literal`.

This is my code:

[image]

Comment: can you post some code? This way no one can help you

Comment: Please keep comments productive, obviously this is a user's first post, we all were beginners at one point in time, be kind and constructive

Comment: Note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Comment: @NathanDay we didn't all ignore the [help], or post *screenshots* of code...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand and agree with your point. However I doubt this is a case of abusing SO, but rather being novice and not knowing. If the user had an account for longer than today, it would be a different story

Comment: @NathanDay no, it wouldn't. Judge the *content*, not the *user*.

Answer (score 1):

You try to do this:

```
'T1' = 'T2'
```

which results ins:

```
    'T1' = 'T2'
               ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

You cannot assign one string literal to another.

You could do something like this:

```
Grid[oldYpos][oldXpos] = 'T2'
```

A full `if` statement:

```
if Grid[oldYpos][oldXpos] == 'T1':
    Grid[oldYpos][oldXpos] = 'T2'
elif Grid[oldYpos][oldXpos] == 'T2':
    Grid[oldYpos][oldXpos] = 'T3'
elif Grid[oldYpos][oldXpos] = 'T3':
    Grid[oldYpos][oldXpos] = 'B'
```

Also better change:

```
if Grid[oldYpos][oldXpos] == 'T1' or 'T2'  or 'T3':
```

in:

```
if Grid[oldYpos][oldXpos] in ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']:
```

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.